# Android how to call web service with parameters and get jsonarray as responce

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to implement pagination in android.currently i have a service which returns jsonarray.

```
protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... params) {

    JSONArray jsonArray = null; 
    String result = ServerConnect.readService("http://myservice.com/resbook_redberry/mobile/GetKitchenOrder");

    try {
        jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        try {
            jsonArray = new JSONArray(result.substring(3));
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return jsonArray;
}
```

but now I need to send page number to the web service and get `JSONArray` as response.

Do I need to write HTTP post? what things should I change to make this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Try this: here i am using gson library to parse json : https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/detail?name=google-gson-2.2.4-release.zip&can=1&q=

**With GET Method**

    protected SignUpResponseJson doInBackground(String... params) {

        urlString = "http://www.xxxxx.com?page=1"
        url  =  new URL(urlString);

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(Integer.parseInt(context.getResources().getString(R.string.timeout))); //set timeout to 5 seconds
        connection.setReadTimeout(Integer.parseInt(context.getResources().getString(R.string.timeout))); //set timeout to 5 seconds

        connection.connect();

        HttpURLConnection httpConnection  =  (HttpURLConnection) connection;
        int responseCode  =  httpConnection.getResponseCode();
        //      Log.i("test-responsecode",String.valueOf(responseCode));
        if (responseCode   ==   HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            //          Log.i("test","inside if");
            InputStream in  =  httpConnection.getInputStream();
            Gson gson  =  new Gson();
            Reader r  =  new InputStreamReader(in);

            Type DataType  =  new TypeToken<SignUpResponseJson>() {
            }.getType();

            signUpResponseJsons  =  gson.fromJson(r,DataType);
            Log.i(TAG, gson.toJson(signUpResponseJsons).toString());

        }

    }
```

**OR With Post Method**

http://fahmirahman.wordpress.com/2011/04/26/the-simplest-way-to-post-parameters-between-android-and-php/

```
public void postData(){  
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yourdomain.com/post.php");  

        try {
            // Add your data
            List nameValuePairs = new ArrayList(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data1", "dataValue"));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));  

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer..but what i need is posting page number to the server and get the json array according to that request. Are you posting any values to server before getting the json?

Comment: yes..but unfortunately it not accepts parameters via url. is there any option to send parameters to server other than url?